# PhpStorm / ESLint shows validation using vuejs/draggable component

Tags: vuejs2, phpstorm, eslint

In my @vue/cli 4.0.5 / ESLint app I add vuedraggable 2.24.1 and in  PhpStorm 2019.2.3  I see validation errors:

[image]

Meanwhile the app works OK and I do not have runtime errors.
I suppose that reason of the errors is in `ul` definition, as :

```html
<draggable
    class="list-group"
    handle=".tasks_handle"
    :sort="false"
    tag="ul" // !!!
    v-model="processingTasks"
```

If there is a way to remove/hide this error?

In package.json I have I have ESLint options set :

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {
      "semi": [
        2,
        "never"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: what errors can you see namely, do they really come from ESLint? Also, what is `<draggable>`? Is it your own Vue.js component, or something provided by a library available on the web?

Comment: That is component from https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable.  I suppose that ESLint shows these errors

Comment: *"I suppose that ESLint shows these errors"* Hover over the warning/error to see the tooltip with error message and then post a screenshot of that here -- it will show what the error is and the source (ESLint or something else).

Comment: all tooltips show message “Closing tag match nothing”

Comment: can't reproduce with similar code; please share the `.vue` file the issue can be repeated with

Comment: Could you please try example code from https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable  with <draggable block?